# Node JS Cache Error : this.__parentArray.$path is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, caching

Im using this library [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) to cache  mongo db queries like below,

```
import NodeCache from "node-cache";

const cache = new NodeCache({ stdTTL: 60, checkperiod: 80 });

export async function checkCache(req, res) {
  let brands = cache.get("brands");
  if (brands == undefined) {
    try {
      brands = await brandModel.find({});
      cache.set("brands", brands);
      res.send({
        status: 1000,
        data: brands,
        message: "FROM DATA BASE",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      res.send({
        status: 2000,
        data: null,
        message: error.message,
      });
    }
  } else {
    res.send({
      status: 1000,
      data: brands,
      message: "From CACHE",
    });
  }
}
```

I'm always getting error :

```
{
    "status": 2000,
    "data": null,
    "message": "this.__parentArray.$path is not a function"
}
```

And if I remove the `cache.set("brands", brands);` line the code works without any issues !! any help or ideas will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved, I had to use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` with the cached data like below,

```
export async function checkCache(req, res) {
  let brands = cache.get("brands");
  if (brands == undefined) {
    try {
      brands = await brandModel.find({});
      cache.set("brands", JSON.stringify(brands));
      res.send({
        status: 1000,
        data: brands,
        message: "FROM DATA BASE",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      res.send({
        status: 2000,
        data: null,
        message: error.message,
      });
    }
  } else {
    res.send({
      status: 1000,
      data: JSON.parse(brands),
      message: "From CACHE",
    });
  }
}
```

Note :  This issue only presented with array of objects